# Cannot delete directory

Tags: linux, windows, command-line

So I installed the new Blade & Soul game and long story short the launcher crashed halfway through install and refused to load afterwards. I tried to reinstall the application however the installer didn't actually delete the directory, I then preceded to attempt to delete it by right clicking and deleting in windows. This did not work either so I went into command prompt with administrative permission and used the command `rmdir /S /Q NCSOFT`. This returned an error saying that the directory is not empty which I thought the /S parameter solved.

Anyway after furious browsing of the INTERNET for a fix I booted up Lite Linux on a live usb, and attempted to delete the directory once again. So I navigated my way in the command prompt to my mounted windows file system, and typed `rm -rf NCSOFT` it returned the errors:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘NCSOFT/BnS/bin’: Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove ‘NCSOFT/BnS/contents/bns/CookedPC’: Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove ‘NCSOFT/BnS/contents/Local/NCWEST/ENGLISH/CookedPC’: Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove ‘NCSOFT/BnS/contents/Local/NCWEST/web/common/character/skin/14’: Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove ‘NCSOFT/BnS/contents/Local/NCWEST/web/common/character/skin/15’: Directory not empty
```

So I returned to the Internet for more info on my issue and discovered that a corrupt file system code be the case and saw that I could use the command `btrfsk --repair` on the **"corrupt"** file system. I tried this to no avail and once again was returned with an error message:

```
pair /media/linux/AC46C18046C14BB0
enabling repair mode
Could not open /media/linux/AC46C18046C14BB0
Couldn't open file system
```

Thank you for anyone in advance that takes their spare time to help me I just want to solve this issue so that I can install Blade and Soul and play with my friends ayyy :) .

Comment: Performing a recursive forced delete ( -rf) should work. Have you tried running this with sudo? It does come across as a permissions issue at first glance. Whats the user/group on the NCSOFT folder (ls -l)?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo rm -rf directoryname`?

Comment: You can also try this ==> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/79699-undeletable-file-delete.html

Comment: @AaronLayfield here's what I got from using that with sudo:

'rm: cannot remove ‘NCSOFT/BnS/bin’: Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove ‘NCSOFT/BnS/contents/bns/CookedPC’: Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove ‘NCSOFT/BnS/contents/Local/NCWEST/ENGLISH/CookedPC’: Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove ‘NCSOFT/BnS/contents/Local/NCWEST/web/common/character/skin/14’: Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove ‘NCSOFT/BnS/contents/Local/NCWEST/web/common/character/skin/15’: Directory not empty'


ls -l brought me this 'drwx------ 1 linux linux     0 Jan 21 11:09 NCSOFT'

Comment: @AaronLayfield this isn't a permissions issue, the error would be different. `sudo` won't make any difference. Curtis, I've seen this sort of thing happen with network file systems. What filesystem are you using? Is it a local drive? Is it actually a btrfs system? Does using `find NCSOFT -delete` do any better?